# _functools module

Tags: python, extension-modules

How does this import work, what file does it use?

```
import _functools
```

In python 2.5:

```
import _functools
print _functools.__file__
```

Gives:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\zjm_code\mysite\zjmbooks\a.py", line 5, in <module>
    print _functools.__file__
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__file__'
```

How can I get the meaning of partial (from _functools import partial) if I can't read C code?

Comment: The implementation of `functools` is in C for 2.5 and 2.6. If you want to see the source, you'll *have* to read C. There seems to be a difference in the way it's compiled on my distro but either way, the source is in `C`. Check out the links to the repo in my answer if you want to see the source.

Comment: zjm: Don't use non-public (`_*`) modules directly, and view the documentation for functools.partial at http://docs.python.org/library/functools.html#functools.partial.

Comment: +1 for not using the (semi) private modules prefixed by `_`.

Comment: thanks@ Noufal Ibrahim,@ Roger Pate

Comment: This is very old but, sometimes I like to use private functions, methods, etc. Particularly in `asyncio` because there are a lot of API like `loop._write_to_self` to allow threadsafety in otherwise non-threadsafe methods. Or to "cut corners" and run a function closer to the implementation rather than running through the public version, such as `asyncio.tasks_wait` over `asyncio.wait`. It's marginal but I like to optimize as long as I'm aware, and as long as it won't lead to a ridiculous looking codebase or something. But that is subjective, as some are against using private methods at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C-coded modules can be built-in (lacking `__file__`) or live in a `.so` or `.pyd` dynamic library (which their `__file__` will indicate) -- that's an implementation detail that you should not care about.

If you want to understand how a Python-callable, C-coded function works by studying code, learning to **read** C is generally best (far less hard than actually productively *coding* in C;-).  However, often you'll find (suggestive, non-authoritative) "sample Python implementations" of C-coded functionality, and you can study *those*.

A particularly fruitful repository of Python-coded equivalents to Python standard library functionality that's normally coded in C is the [pypy](http://codespeak.net/pypy/dist/pypy/doc/) project (which does Python implementations coded in Python) -- its sources are browseable [here](http://codespeak.net/svn/pypy/trunk/) and of course you can download and peruse them on your machine.

In particular, this is pypy's [_functools.py](http://codespeak.net/svn/pypy/trunk/pypy/lib/_functools.py) implementation:

```
""" Supplies the internal functions for functools.py in the standard library """

class partial:
    """
    partial(func, *args, **keywords) - new function with partial application
    of the given arguments and keywords.
    """
    __slots__ = ['func', 'args', 'keywords']

    def __init__(self, func, *args, **keywords):
        if not callable(func):
            raise TypeError("the first argument must be callable")
        self.func = func
        self.args = args
        self.keywords = keywords

    def __call__(self, *fargs, **fkeywords):
        newkeywords = self.keywords.copy()
        newkeywords.update(fkeywords)
        return self.func(*(self.args + fargs), **newkeywords)
```

Pretty trivial to read and understand, I hope!

Answer (score 1):

For Python2.6, 
The `_functools` module is a builtin. You can see that if you simply type `import _functools ; repr(_functools)` and hit enter at your interpreter prompt.

If you want to see the C source of the module, check out http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/d7e85ddb1336/Modules/_functoolsmodule.c

This `_functools` module doesn't have a `__file__` attribute (see next paragraph) since it's compiled into the interpreter.

For Python2.5, 
The `_functools` module is a standard library module implemented in C and is available at http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/a78381ead4cf/Modules/_functoolsmodule.c if you want to see it. You can see the location from where the module is loaded up by typing `import _functools ; print _functools.__file__` at your interpreter prompt

Answer (score 0):

please be more clear when asking questions next time. I assume you want this

```
>>> import _functools
>>> _functools.__file__
'/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload/_functools.so'
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a shared object `_functools.so`, written in C. I guess, it is imported by the actual `functools` module. Why are you trying to import from it? Sure, it is possible, however, you can just as well `from functools import partial`.

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour of the `functools.partial()` function is described in [PEP 309](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0309/) in which it was defined. The although the actual implementations of built-ins are often in C PEP's including this one usually contain [example implementations in Python](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0309/#example-implementation).

This example code should be sufficient for you to understand the behaviour of `functools.partial()`. If there is a specific issue about the C implementation that is concerning you are going to have to read the C code. Or perhaps describe it in your question and someone might know the answer.