# Model sys's python implementation

Tags: python, model, pypy

[pypy](http://codespeak.net/pypy/dist/pypy/doc/)

has many built-in function  use python implementation.example:[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2032677/functools-module)

but,i can't find  model 'sys' implementation.

how can i get it.

```
import sys
print help(sys)
```

Comment: source of which function do you want from `sys`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sys module is implemented in C: http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/Python/sysmodule.c?view=markup

There is no Python source for it, because it's entirely operating system interfaces that cannot be implemented in pure Python.

Comment: `sys` provides functions crucial to the interpreter, and is really more of a reflection of interpreter state, so it is actually compiled in when the interpreter is built, and the values are all guaranteed to change at runtime. Pypy would have to use their own implementation of sys.

Answer (score 0):

Abstraction can only be taken so far, Python strives to be a system/platform independent language and the sys module being what it is has to be platform specific and cannot be implemented in pure python.